# Python Matplotlib y-axis scale into multiple spacing ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

When plotting this data, how do I get the log scale on the y-axis similar to the first picture?

```
Power       BER
-32.87825   0.001690592
-28.42475   1.039675E-09
-30.640749  6.759033E-06
-32.8139954 0.001475279
-31.92425   0.0002321081
-31.12975   2.978612E-05
-30.3422489 2.531642E-06
-29.5207443 1.218128E-07
-28.76425   5.379717E-09
-27.95625   1.482309E-10
-27.162     5E-12
-29.2860775 1E-07
```

[image: BER plot]

I am being able to plot like this

```
axes.semilogy(Power,BER,marker='x',label='LTLV',linestyle='',linewidth = linewidth1, ms = ms1)
axes.set_yscale('logit')
```

[image: My MATPLOTLIB]

Comment: How did you generate the first plot and what it the radio between the successive powers of ten?

Comment: It was created through software, which I do not want.
the radio? I think you are asking about the distance between the two y grid lines, while it is decreasing as the values are going near to 10e-14.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What about my second question?

Comment: I want to figure out how to radically decrease the y axis ticks in the matplotlib. 
The first picture is from commercial software, I have to manually put data from excel into that software to produce such a graph. The data is in an excel sheet, so I can use pandas to get access to that data and through matplotlib I can generate the graph.

Comment: And what is the ratio between the successive powers?

Comment: 10e-1 but you can see in the graph that the distance between two y-axis ticks at top is bigger than the two y-axis ticks at the bottom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235988/discussion-between-liaquat85-and-mozway).

Comment: Obviously, I meant the ratio **on the visual representation**…